# Visual Studio 2015 Cordova TypeScript Platform-specific TS files

Tags: cordova, typescript, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform, visual-studio-cordova

I want to add platform specific TS files to the merges\\scripts directory.  I assume that vanilla JS files override the same named file in \scripts.  When I do the same with TS, my same named functions are getting flagged as an error.  What's the right way to handle this?

Android-specific
[image: Android-specific]

Windows-specific
[image: Windows-specific]

Platform-agnostic (PROJECT\scripts)
[image: Platform-agnostic/<project> scripts]

Comment: Have you checked how your .ts-files in your merges directory get compiled into .js-files? Maybe the naming is not correct...

Comment: The only config I have is the tsconfig in PROJECT\Scripts.  This is the contents: {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "out": "www/scripts/appBundle.js",
    "target": "es5"
  }
}